# Where are the elements of the cartesian product contained?

Tags: set-theory

If one defines ordered products to be $(a,b) := \{a,\{a, b\}\}$ one further define the cartesian product of two sets $x$ and $y$ to be:

$$x \times y:=\{(a,b)|a \in x \land b \in y\}.$$

Now, in order for $x \times y$ to be a set (by the principle of restricted comprehension) we must also, in principle, specify the set, lets call it $M$, in which we contain the ordered pairs:

$$x \times y:=\{(a,b)\in M|a \in x \land b \in y\}.$$

My guess is that $M$ must have something to do with unions and power sets (I denote the power set of a set $x$ by $P(x)$). The best I could think of is something like:

$$M= P\left(\cup\{P(x),P(y)\} \right),$$

but I'm not sure if I'm missing anything. Is this the right set? (Of course there are many sets that include all the ordered pairs, so even if this one is a good choice, is there a - "simpler" so to say - subset of this that would also do the job?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we're looking at the set $\{\{a,\{a,b\}\}\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$.

Since $\{a,b\}\subseteq A\cup B$, it is an element of $\mathcal P(A\cup B)$, therefore $\{a,\{a,b\}\}$ is a subset of $A\cup\mathcal P(A\cup B)$, and therefore an element of $\mathcal P(A\cup\mathcal P(A\cup B))$.

If you don't like the notation $A\cup B$, it is a shorthand for $\bigcup\{A,B\}$, so we can rewrite it as $\mathcal P(\bigcup\{A,\mathcal P(\bigcup\{A,B\})\})$. But that's just insistence on making things unreadable for humans.